ASP.NET set output path of a project
The Case
I have an ASP.NET MVC project referencing a web project like this:
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\callcenter.client\callcenter.client.esproj">
    <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>

On publishing the ASP.NET MVC project, it outputs to bin folder and the web outputs to wwwroot folder inside it.
The Problem
I have other files and folders inside wwwroot, and I want the web project to output to a sub directory inside wwwroot. I have no clue how to do that.

This question is similar to: ASP.NET Core publish of wwwroot subfolders starting with '.'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@burcu The question that you cite is about controlling the publish of a project. This question is about pulling content from another project via a ProjectReference. These are different mechanisms within MSBuild.
